# Convert js web template into Angular 2+ application

Tags: angular, web-applications, web-frontend

I have a web template that is made with bare js and all the html's and a lot of plugins, such as jQuery, bootstrap, etc.

The point is I want to use Angular 7 (because it's the only framework I know well) to make a new website based on this template, and since I am relatively new to front-end development, this is turning very hard to me.

So the question is, is there any way to "translate" or "convert" all the structure of the template into an angular-friendly structure? Are there any alternatives?

PS: The template does include an AngularJS version, but not an Angular 2+'s, if helps

Answer (score 0):

In general, I don't think there is any automatic way of "converting" plain javascript code to an Angular format.

If the template includes an AngularJS version though, `angular.io` has an [AngularJS upgrade guide](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade) which goes over the process of upgrading an AngularJS application to an Angular application. It also allows you to incrementally convert to Angular. My guess is that'll be your best bet.